# How can I optimize my build for large (10+ players) parties?

Tags: dnd-5e, optimization, party

I plan to soon join a 5e group with over 10 PCs in the party at any given time. Are there any feats, builds, classes, etc that can be used to capitalize on this very large party size?

This may seem like a very broad question, but I'm struggling to find anything at all that meets this criteria, so I can only assume that few answers exist. The obvious solution was to seek out anything that affects something like "all allies within 30 feet", but I've had difficulty finding any such thing. The first place that I checked was the Battle Master Fighter's maneuvers, but all of those seem to only affect one ally at a time. Furthermore, due to Bardic Inspiration allowing only a single target, the Bard has very similar restrictions. Where else can I look? Anything is on the table. I have no restrictions in my class or build choice.

Comment: Have you checked out spells? If not, is there any particular reason for not doing that, for example not wanting to play a spellcaster? [note: this is not a partial-answer-in-the-comments, I'm just trying to gauge how much research OP has done. Battle Master maneuvers and Bardic Inspiration are far from the first places I myself would check)

Comment: @PixelMaster Spells are an option. The most interesting thing that I've found is Hallow, but it doesn't seem to fit the bill.

Comment: The first question is.. what is "your build"? What are you willing to play, looking forward to playing, accomplishing with this character? There is no point in listing a bunch of spells if you don't want to be a spellcaster.

Comment: @MivaScott Anything is on the table.

Comment: Why the close votes? I thought that I had explained why the set of valid answers should be quite small.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Feats

As far feats, two stand out. Healer and Inspiring leader allow a bonus per target per short rest. With 10 party members Inspiring leader can be giving out lots of temporary hp (although it will need 2 speeches)

### As a Paladin

You are correct that AoE bonuses are the most powerful in that situation. Some examples are Paladin Aura of Protection bonus to all friendly creatures within 10 feet. (spreading to 30 at level 17). Similarly the Aura of Warding or Aura of Devotion would have more potential targets.

Another Paladin spell which shines in large groups is Crusader's Mantle

> Holy power radiates from you in an aura with a 30-foot radius, awakening boldness in friendly creatures. Until the spell ends, the aura moves with you, centered on you. While in the aura, each nonhostile creature in the aura (including you) deals an extra 1d4 radiant damage when it hits with a weapon attack.

In fact most aura spells work best in larger groups.

### As a Barbarian

The most big group savvy barbarian I can recommend is Path of the Ancestral Guardian. You effectively can protect a large group with their utility abilities.

### As a Druid

Circle of the Shepard provides several Aura like abilities.

Also Pass without Trace is strong as it makes your entire group (within range) very stealthy.

Answer (score 6):

## Use buff spells.

While many multi-target buff spells impose a limit on the number of targets that can be affected, some do not. [By filtering spells on D&D Beyond by the "buff" tag](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells?filter-tags=11&filter-source-category=1&filter-source-category=12), a number of spells is shown. Among these, several do not impose a creature limit, such as (incomplete list!):

- Beacon of Hope
- Circle of Power
- most aura spells (life, purity, holy)
- Crusader's Mantle
- Heroes Feast (expensive, costs 1000gp worth of materials and has to be cast in preparation)

Filtering by "healing" or "shapechanging" can also yield results, such as:

- Healing Spirit, if your DM lets you abuse it by having every party member run through it on their turn
- Animal Shapes
- Mass Polymorph

These are most likely not *all* spells that can buff groups of people, but they're a good start. Beyond that, I suggest you simply take a look at D&D Beyond or your PHB yourself to figure out which other spells might be suitable.

Comment: Healing Spirit has been significantly nerfed in errata. It has a very limited number of activations (1+Casting Mod), making it far less abusable.

Comment: Heroes' Feast does impose a limit (up to twelve other creatures can partake), though that limit is very high.

Comment: @LouisWasserman that's true, but since OP asked for group sizes of 10+, I figured it would still be applicable. And if there really are more than 12 players, they should probably have two players capable of casting it, so they can just cast it twice. That technically also applies to spells with a limit of, say, 3 people, but not as much.